# Run .bat file with Administrative rights

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

My PowerShell script runs a .bat file to install an .msu file. But I need to run this .bat file with Administrator rights.

The .bat file is:

```
WUSA C:\temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu /quiet /norestart
```

I have Domain Controller and a lot of clients. With PowerShell PS session I interactively connect to every client. I need to use this bat file with Domain Admin credentials, how can I do this?

Comment: As a side note, best practice is accounts in Domain Admins aren't used to run on clients and you use another account for Local Admin tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Invoke-Command`

You could save the servers in list in a text file and then use the `Get-Content` command to save the array in a variable:

```
$clients = Get-Content C:\ExampleClientList.txt
```

Then use the variable for the `ComputerName` parameter of `Invoke-Command`. Then in the `scriptblock` parameter is where you run the command, since you can run executables in PowerShell there isn't any need for the bat file. Last the `Credential` parameter will allow you run this as the Local administrator.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $clients -ScriptBlock {WUSA C:\temp\Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu /quiet /norestart} -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure i understand your question.

To start batch file from powershell you can use start-proccess command:

```
powershell start-process <path to your file> -verb RunAs
```

Comment: If you don't understand a question, then it's best practice to ask for clarification in a comment. Luca9698 is using `Enter-PSSession` to interactively connect to each computer then run the .bat file. This is unnecessary as that command can be run directly in PowerShell. And if the task needs to be run in parallel, it can be done with `Invoke-Command`